# How do I lock my iOS application's orientation to portrait only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

I am using Xcode 6 and iOS. I just created a new project to test out the following code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return NO;
}
```

I inserted it in `ViewController.m` under the `@implementation ViewController`, yet when I simulate it, I am still able to rotate it using Command + Right Arrow. Is that the correct way to lock an application to use only the default portrait orientation?

Answer (score 3):

Change "Device Orientation" under Project -> Targets -> Deployment Info:

[image]